# Using Event Aggregator to load a view with different model in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to backbone.js started with backbone a week ago. I had to make a demo. The main idea behind it is when the page is loaded, I need to show the courses,and by default the students list for the first course in the list. Here is the code to display the course list which is in **course.js** file

***//Model***

```
  var Course = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/courses/',
    idAttribute: 'Id', 
    defaults:{
        Id: null,
        Name: ""        
    },
    validate: function (attr) {
        if (!attr.Name)
            return "Name is required";          
      }
});

var Courses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Course,
    url: '/api/courses'
});
```

***//Views***

```
var CourseList = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.renderAll, this);
        this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
        _.bindAll(this, 'renderAll', 'render');
        return this;
    },
    renderAll: function () {
        this.collection.each(this.render);
        $('#spnStdntCourseName').text('Students Enrolled in ' + this.collection.at(0).get("Name"));
    },
    render: function (model) {
        var item = new CourseItem({ model: model });
        this.$el.append(item.el);
    },

    events: {
        "click    #btnAddCourse": "createNewCourse",
        "keypress #txtNewCourse": "createOnEnter"
    },

    createOnEnter: function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            this.createNewCourse();
        }
    },
    createNewCourse: function () {
        this.collection.create({ Name: this.$el.find('#txtNewCourse').val() });
        this.$el.find('#txtNewCourse').val('');
    }
});


var CourseItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'courseli',
    events: {
        'click .remove': 'deleteItem',
        'click .edit': 'showEdit',
        'click': 'courseClicked'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('#course').html()),
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html('').html(html);
    },

    courseClicked: function () {
        $('#spnStdntCourseName').text('Students Enrolled in ' + this.model.get("Name"));
        Vent.trigger('studentDetails',"how to load student list from here based on courseID...?");
    },

    showEdit: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Vent.trigger('edit', this.model);
    },
    deleteItem: function () {
        this.model.destroy();
        this.remove();
    }
});


var CourseEdit = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#courseEdit',
    events: {
        'click #save': 'save',
        'click #cancel': 'cancel'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'save');
        Vent.on('edit', this.render);
        this.template = _.template($('#courseEditTemplate').html())
    },
    render: function (model) {
        var data, html;
        this.model = model;
        data = this.model.toJSON();
        html = this.template(data);
        this.$el.html(html)
        .show()
        .find('#name')
        .focus();
        this.model.on('error', this.showErrors, this);
    },
    save: function (event) {
        var self = this;
        this.model.save({
            'Name': this.$el.find('#name').val()
        }, {
            success: function () {
                alert('Saved!');
                if (!window.courses.any(function (course) {
                    return course.get('Id') === self.model.get('Id');
                })) {
                    window.courses.add(self.model);
                }
                self.$el.hide();
            }
        });
    },
    cancel: function () {
        this.$el.hide();
    },
    showErrors: function (model, error) {
        var errors = '';
        if (typeof error === 'object') {
            errors = JSON.parse(error.responseText).join('<br/>');
            alert(errors);
        }
        else {
            alert(error);
        }
    }
});

var Vent = _.extend({ }, Backbone.Events);
window.courses = new Courses();
$(function () {
  var edit = new CourseEdit(),
    list = new CourseList({
        collection: window.courses,
        el: '#coursesList'
    });
});
```

Please take a look at the **'courseClicked'** function inside **CourseItem** View, it is supposed to load the students list when a course item is clicked.

Now I have my **Student** model and views in students.js as below

```
var Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: '/api/students/',
idAttribute: 'Id',
defaults: {
    Id: null
},
validate: function (attr) {
    if (!attr.Name)
        return "Name is required";
}
});

var Students = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Student,
url: '/api/students'
});
```

**//Views**

```
var StudentList = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'ul',
initialize: function () {
    this.collection.on('reset', this.renderAll, this);
    this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
    this.collection.fetch({ data: $.param({ courseId: 11 }) });
    _.bindAll(this, 'renderAll', 'render');
    return this;
  Vent.on('studentDetails', this.render);
},
renderAll: function () {
    this.collection.each(this.render);
},
render: function (model) {
    var item = new StudentItem({ model: model });
    this.$el.append(item.el);
},

events: {
    "click    #btnAddStudent": "createNewStudent",
    "keypress #txtNewStudent": "createOnEnter"
},

createOnEnter: function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        this.createNewStudent();
    }
},
createNewStudent: function () {
    this.collection.create({ Name: this.$el.find('#txtNewStudent').val() });
    this.$el.find('#txtNewStudent').val('');
}
```

});

```
var StudentItem = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'li',
className: 'studentli',
events: {
    'click .remove': 'deleteItem',
    'click': 'studentClicked'
},

initialize: function () {
    this.template = _.template($('#student').html()),
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    this.render();
},
render: function () {
    var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html('').html(html);
},

studentClicked: function () {
    var Id = this.model.get("Id");
},

deleteItem: function () {
    this.model.destroy();
    this.remove();
}
```

});

```
window.students = new Students();
$(function () {
   var studentDetails = new StudentList({
        collection: window.students,
        el: '#studentsList'
    });      
});
```

so inside document.ready I have **studentDetails** variable which loads the students list.Here is my problem as of now I have loaded the students list on page load by passing some hard code parameter inside fetch like below

```
 this.collection.fetch({ data: $.param({ courseId: 11 }) });
```

but what I need to show is, the student list for the first course in the courselist view when the page is loaded, and in later stages, the student list for each and every course item clicked.For that purpose if you can remember in the "courseClicked" function inside "CourseItem" view in course.js, I have used

```
 Vent.trigger('studentDetails',"how to load student list from here based on courseID...?");
```

studentDetails is the var that I have initialised in students.js(in the code above) like this

```
window.students = new Students();
$(function () {
var studentDetails = new StudentList({
    collection: window.students,
    el: '#studentsList'
});      
});
```

So when I trigger the studentDetails I defnitely be needing the student model inside my courseClicked function,which is not available in that context. I beleive you guys understood my problem from the above explanation. So how do I fix this...? Is the approach I followed wrong..? Any good alternative,need suggestions. Hope there is not too much noise in the question.

**EDIT**

```
var CourseList = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'ul',
initialize: function () {
this.students = new Students();
var studentList = new StudentList({
  collection: this.students,
  el: '#studentsList'
});

this.collection.on('reset', this.renderAll, this);
this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
this.collection.fetch();
_.bindAll(this, 'renderAll', 'render');
return this;
},

renderAll: function () {
    this.collection.each(this.render);
    $('#spnStdntCourseName').text('Students Enrolled in ' +    this.collection.at(0).get("Name"));
    this.students.fetch({ data: $.param({ courseId: this.collection.at(0).get("Id") }) });
},
render: function (model) {
this.$el.html("");
var item = new CourseItem({ model: model, students: this.students});
this.$el.append(item.el);   
}
})
```

I have made following changes

1.students in collection to this.students(inside initialize of "CourseList" view) in the below code

```
initialize: function () {
    this.students = new Students();
    var studentList = new StudentList({
        collection: this.students,
        el: '#studentsList'
    });
```

2.I have fetched the students inside renderAll function instead of render function because for every course item that is fetched the student is also fetched.I mean if there are 6 courses i get to see the students for course 0 in the collection 6 times

```
 renderAll: function () {
    this.collection.each(this.render);
    $('#spnStdntCourseName').text('Students Enrolled in ' +    this.collection.at(0).get("Name"));
    this.students.fetch({ data: $.param({ courseId: this.collection.at(0).get("Id") }) });
```

**SubQuestion**

In the "CourseList" we have initialize function as below

```
 initialize: function () {
    this.students = new Students();
    var studentList = new StudentList({
        collection: this.students,
        el: '#studentsList'
    });
```

The studentsList el is as below

```
<div id="studentsList" class="box">
<div class="box-head">
    <h2 class="left">
        <span id="spnStdntCourseName"></span>
    </h2>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="text" id="txtNewStudent" placeholder="Add New Student" />
    <button id = "btnAddStudent">+ Add</button>    
</div>       
</div>
```

whenever I do this.$el.html("") inside render function of **StudentList** view like below

```
var StudentList = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'ul',

render: function (model) {
this.$el.html("");
    var item = new StudentItem({ model: model });
    this.$el.append(item.el);
},
......
```

I loose the button and textbox elements inside the studentsList el, and the ul is not shown when I view source code in my browser which I mentioned as tagName, but I do see li which is tagName for studentItem view.Can you say what I am doing wrong

Thanks for our patience

Comment: I would assume that I could `GET /api/students/:courseId` to get all the students in that courseId?

Comment: Sorry, never mind, you used `$.param` to fetch the students instead.

Comment: Regarding clearing out the thing. It's better that you use a template for rendering just the students instead of appending to a DIV with existing elements. That way you can just replace the content of that template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you want to let the `CourseList` view to keep track of a `Students` collection as well as a `StudentList`. The `Students` collection will be passed into each `CourseItem` view to fetch. After it renders all `CourseItem`, it will tell the `Students` collection to fetch the first course's students.

```js
var CourseList = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  initialize: function () {
    this.students = new Students();
    var studentList = new StudentList({
      collection: students,
      el: '#studentsList'
    });

    this.collection.on('reset', this.renderAll, this);
    this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
    this.collection.fetch();
    _.bindAll(this, 'renderAll', 'render');
    return this;
  },

  render: function (model) {
    this.$el.html("");
    var item = new CourseItem({ model: model, students: this.students});
    this.$el.append(item.el);
    this.students.fetch({ data: $.param({ courseId: 0 }) }); // fetch the first
  },
  ...
})
```

The `CourseItem` will store the `Students` collection, and on being clicked, fetch the correct students using its model's id.

```js
var CourseItem = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  initialize: function() {
    this.students = this.options.students;
  },
  ...
  courseClicked: function () {  
    $('#spnStdntCourseName').text('Students Enrolled in ' + this.model.get("Name"));

    var courseId = this.model.id;
    this.students.fetch({ data: $.param({ courseId: courseId }) });
  },
  ...
})
```

In `StudentList` view, you don't let it fetch by itself.

```js
var StudentList = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  initialize: function () {
      this.collection.on('reset', this.renderAll, this);
      this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
      _.bindAll(this, 'renderAll', 'render');
      return this;
  },
  ...

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(""); // Reset the view for new students
    var item = new StudentItem({ model: model });
    this.$el.append(item.el);
  }
})
```

Then in your main script:

```js
window.courses = new Courses();

$(function () {
   var courseList = new CourseList({
        collection: window.course,
        el: '#courseList'
    });
});
```

DISCLAIMER: Untested codes.

Comment: this works like a charm, but one issue is when i click on the course item i am seeing the students of the clicked course and also the previous course...is it related to ghost view...?

Comment: one more question :) can you please say how will i be able to show the students of the first course item as soon as the page loads..?

Comment: theres is a code duplication here right..? In student.js file like i mentioned above ,there in the document.ready I have written the same code that is written now inside 'courseClicked' :|.

Comment: Do I have to write courseList.fetch() because I already mentioned it in my initialize function of "CourseList" view and removing it shows me the courses tho

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK. The first issue with seeing duplicated students was because the `CourseList` view was not reset. Need to clear that view before append any `CourseItem` view.

You would not want to initialize the students in document.ready because you don't know which students to fetch for. Let the `CourseItem` view handle that.

Yes, I did not read `CourseList` carefully, thus the duplicate `courseList.fetch` there. Sorry.

I'm still thinking about loading the first course.

Comment: Thanks for patiently answering the question.I had to make some changes to the solution u gave which i will make an edit now in the question

Comment: @ sntran I have issues with the view clearing.Please refer to the SubQuestion I have written in the question

Comment: gets an upvote reading and responding to that query phrased as a novella