# How to set the id of clicked item of one collection as attribute for another collection using backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to backbone and I am stuck with a problem

**problem in short**

I have two lists to be shown.

1.Courses

2.Students for selected course

which I am able to show now.

Now in the **StudentList view**(it uses **"Students" collection**) I have an add button,which adds the student for the selected course item(**which is in separate view**). For that I need to know which course item I have clicked inside the **StudentList view**. For that I have stored the courseId in a hidden field when a course is clicked and later in **StudentList view** I have fetched that hidden field value to add the new student.

What I want to do is **instead of storing the courseId in a hidden field**,can I **add the courseId to the "Students" collection as an attribute when a course is clicked**.

**Tried Approach**

Inside StudentList view I have written something like this

```
var StudentList = Backbone.View.extend({
 initialize: function () {
    this._meta = {};       
},  

put: function (prop, value) {
    this._meta[prop] = value;
},
get: function (prop) {
    return this._meta[prop];
},   
events: {
    "click    #btnAddStudent": "createNewStudent"
},

createNewStudent: function () {      
    var some =  this.get("someProp");       
    this.collection.create({ Name: this.$el.find('#txtNewStudent').val(), 
    CourseId: some  });       
}
});
```

And in "courseClicked" function I have done like this(the "courseClicked" function is inside the **CourseItem view**)

```
var CourseItem = Backbone.View.extend({  
events: {        
    'click': 'courseClicked'
},
initialize: function () {
    this.students = this.options.students;
},  
courseClicked: function () {
    var courseId = this.model.id;
    this.students.put('someProp',courseId);
    this.students.fetch({ data: { courseId: courseId} });
}   
});
```

The above doesn't work because put and get functions are not available in the courseitem view context,they are defined in StudentList view.Can anyone guide me how to accomplish my needs.

This question is continuation to the one I posted earlier on **SO** here 
[Using Event Aggregator to load a view with different model in backbone js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959267/using-event-aggregator-to-load-a-view-with-different-model-in-backbone-js/10961588#10961588)
This link might help to know further details of my question.

Thanks for your patience

Comment: I didn't have time to write you short letter so I wrote you a long one - Mark Twain

Comment: You may want to edit the post to shorten it, IMHO

Comment: @Nupul I know the question is long,but to make my requirement clear I had to post this long one,but anyways I have edited it now and tried to make i as short as I can,anymore shorter I believe it will be hard to understand.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @bhargav I still think it is long. May be you could put a conceptual understanding of what should happen, but is happening. ex: 
- Every task has subtasks and must be displayed when viewing tasks(the concept). 

- By clicking the task a loading dialog is shown below and subtasks must show as list below the clicked task ( what must happen),

- I am unable to get the clicked task Id to fetch subtasks( problem and what is happening)

Comment: sorry about the long question,ok I will cut it to much simpler one,and also try to make it as clear as i can

Comment: @Deeptechtons please tell me this is short enough .... I am ready to edit it again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be a partial answer which might lead you to right way or into the trenches. Here it goes.

1. It is best that you have 2 views one for Students list and one for course list. Providing a checkbox list should be good for the course list as Students -> Course is one to many relationship.
2. Course(model) should have a selected attribute(only on client, no significance to server side) which you toggle during checkbox click. Courses (collection) should redraw the changed course with highlights etc
3. The Courses(Collection) should be accessible through window object. something like `window.App.Students.Courses` where Courses is an **instance** of Courses collection.
   ex:`window.App.Students.Courses = new window.App.Students.Collection.Courses;`
4. Now when the course is selected and students are selected. You have global access to courses that have been selected ( which can be retrieved using underscore.js methods) then set the course id into a array for the selected students. something like `for each selectedstudent ( foreach selectedCourse selectedStudent.course.push(selectedCourse))`. json for student will then look like below

`{
        id: 1,
        name: "Jack Keane",
        courses: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
 }`

#### Code

Inside the Student view, do the following to get the selected courses for the student.

```
window.courses.filter(function(course){
  return course.get("selected");
});
```

use the [filter](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) method for obtaining the selected courses. Then assign the course to the student as in #4.

```
var selectedCourses =     window.courses.filter(function(course){
      return course.get("selected");
    });

this.collection.forEach(function(student){

student.set("courses") = selectedCourses;

});
```

by doing the above, every student now has `courses` attribute that gives you the selected courses for this student.

Comment: your answer seems to have no relation to my question. I already have two separate views for CourseList and StudentList and I do have separate views for individual CourseItem and StudentItem too. My only question is: how do I get the CourseId that is clicked in CourseItem view inside the "StudentList" view.Please read my question again.There is no need to have checkboxes for the course list and I do have window.courses which is accessible in my code. anywhere. Your 4th point has nothing to do with my question.Your point 2 seems to be relevant though

Comment: I need to fetch the courseId when adding a new student to the students collection. I have CourseItem view which accepts course model and I have a function called "courseClicked" inside the courseItem view.Please refer the other link i gave in my question for further details